# RSpec check title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

help me please. I need to test view title with rspec, capybara. I have spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
  RSpec.describe 'static_pages/home' do
  it "display correct title" do
    render

    expect(response).to have_title('Home page')
  end
end
```

home.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>djeje Home pagexbdkek</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

RSpec is passed without failures,
but I need to check if title is exactly the same as in spec, not just looking for substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options for Capybara RSpec matchers are the same as for the boolean methods - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/DocumentMatchers:has_title%3F

From that you can see that it takes a string or a regex, and that there is an `exact` option.  Therefore you can do either of

```
expect(response).to have_title(‘Home page’, exact:true)
```

Or

```
expect(response).to have_title(/\AHome page\z/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change that to something like `expect(page).to have_title("Home page", exact: true)`
, which should fail since it does not exactly match the page title.

Comment: It’s better for readability to keep using `have_title` with a regex or the `exact` option.  Also note that when using `find` you can just pass the text to match as the `exact_text` option rather than needing to pass both `text` and a boolean `exact_text`